# Is copyright term linked to the author's lifetime, even after assignment?

Tags: copyright

Assume we have a situation where the copyright term is "70 years from the author's death".

Does this still apply if the author assigns (sells) the copyright before death?

Therefore the valuation of a copyright should include an assessment of the author's health or life-expectancy?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

> Is copyright term linked to the author's lifetime, even after
> assignment?

Yes.

If the original duration of the copyright is measured by the lifetime of the author, an assignment of the copyright is measured by the life of the author.

Some corporate works, however, are not originally measured by the lifetime of an individual author.

> Therefore the valuation of a copyright should include an assessment of
> the author's health or life-expectancy?!

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes in [germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

Even if a company has all exclusive economic rights and the author none, the economic rights run out the moment that the author is dead for 70 years.